# Using TFS 2012 client object model on 64 bit project

Tags: tfs, 32bit-64bit

I have a web project where I am referencing a bunch of the TFS DLLs. Unfortunately, these one's are only built as 32 bit assemblies. So, I get the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

Is there any way I can solve this problem without changing my app pool on IIS to enable 32 bit applications? I can't go that route since I have another DLL (Non TFS one) that's compiled to work only on 64 bit architecture.

Where can I get the 64 bit version of these TFS DLLs? If there aren't any, what are my options to solve this problem?

Comment: Tfs and vs are both 32bit

Comment: @Just TFS
TFS is not limited to 32 bit: the server works perfectly in 64-bit process.

The Windows Client Object Model is limited to 32-bit. I am not sure of the Java client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFS Client Objects are 32 bits only so to use them the process must be 32bit.

In your case the only escape route is to isolate the 32 and 64 bit from each other and some some form of inter-process communication, be it WCF, Shared memory, files on a Temp directory, a Database. As an extreme you can wrap either TFS code or this other 64-bit library in a console project and start a new process to execute some action / compute some values.

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you only need to do basic source control operations is to use the MSSCCI 64-bit provider that can be found here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/22d38324-051c-4f04-9379-ff78e7116c8d